# Why I can't output the result with console.log from Mogoose's Model.find()?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, console, console.log

So I've been working on MongoDB with `mongoose`, and I've got the following code which will be include with `var tdb = require('./db.js');`

```
// ./db.js
module.exports = {
    update: function(data) {
        post.findOne({slug:data.slug}, (err, res) => {
            if(err) {
                post.create(data, (err, res) => {})
            } else {
                post.updateOne({slug:data.slug}, data, (err, res) => {})
            }
        })
    },
    search: function(ftype, fval, fkey) {
        var query = {};
        if(ftype != "all") {
            query[ftype] = fval;
        }
        post.find(query).lean().exec((err, res) => {
            var keys = Object.keys(res);
            var index = keys.indexOf(fkey);
            var rdata = res[fkey];
            rdata.next = res[keys[index + 1]];
            rdata.prev = res[keys[index - 1]];
            return rdata;
        })
    }
}
```

(The code also have other part, but I'm focusing on `search` function)

Which then I try to call `console.log(tdb.search("all", "none", "2"));` but it output `undefined`. But if I add `console.log(rdata)` above the return line, it logs out the correct response while the code `console.log(tdb.search("all", "none", "2"));` still returns `undefined`.

I have no idea why. I've thought of one issue that likely happen is that the process order isn't correct which happened with `fs` and fixed with promise. But I don't think it's the matter since I return the value inside the callback of `post.find()`, which than I'm totally stuck. Have no idea where other can go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your **search** function doesn’t return anything so it will be **undefined** by default.

Also **find** is async. If you remove the callback from **exec**, then it should return a promise. You can then chain a **then** instead and return that promise:

```
search: function(ftype, fval, fkey) {
  var query = {};
  if (ftype != "all") {
    query[ftype] = fval;
  }

  return post
    .find(query)
    .lean()
    .exec()
    .then(res => {
      var keys = Object.keys(res);
      var index = keys.indexOf(fkey);
      var rdata = res[fkey];
      rdata.next = res[keys[index + 1]];
      rdata.prev = res[keys[index - 1]];
      return rdata;
    });
}
```

...and then you should be able to log the result when the promise resolves using **then**:

```
tdb
  .search("all", "none", "2")
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

---

Another way you could do this is to pass a callback function to the **search** function, and then invoke it with the data when ready:

```
search: function(ftype, fval, fkey, callback) {
  var query = {};
  if (ftype != "all") {
    query[ftype] = fval;
  }

  post.find(query).lean().exec((err, res) => {
    var keys = Object.keys(res);
    var index = keys.indexOf(fkey);
    var rdata = res[fkey];
    rdata.next = res[keys[index + 1]];
    rdata.prev = res[keys[index - 1]];

    callback(rdata);
  });
}
```

...and then you should be able to log the result from your callback function:

```
tdb.search("all", "none", "2", (data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

---

I hope this helps.

Comment: It returned `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise you had the callback in there, so it won't return a promise. Try removing the callback from *exec* in the *search* function and using *then* instead. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I've added another option, if you wanted to use a callback instead of promises.

Comment: Both works, but is there a way to do it synchronized? So I can use it directly in `console.log(tdb.search())`. Or it can only be done with callback or promise?

Comment: It's an asynchronous action so you can't handle it in a synchronous manner. It has to go get data from the database. You wouldn't want to block your application during that time.